# showing a dialog just once

Tags: java, android, show

i have a dialog window that have to containers and two on click listeners to close the dialog 
and i want i to be displayed just once and i use this code but it doesn't display it at all!!

any help?

> ```
>     SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("dialogprefs", 0);
>     final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit(); 
>     {
>            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
>             dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>             dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
>             dialog.setContentView(R.layout.hint1);
>             dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
>             dialog.setTitle("Hint");
>             View masterView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
>             masterView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onClick(View view) {
>                     dialog.dismiss();
>                     editor.putString("dialogshow", "0".toString());
>                     editor.commit();
>                 }
>             });
>                 View masterView1 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
>                 masterView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void onClick(View view) {
>                         dialog.dismiss();
>                         editor.putString("dialogshow", "0".toString());
>                         editor.commit();
>                     }
>             });
>             if (setting.getString("dialogshow" , "0").equals("0")) {
>                 dialog.dismiss();
>             }
>             else {
>             dialog.show();  
>             }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Have you tried debugging you application?

Comment: why are you using string, its confusing.. why don't you save boolean which would make sense, false before it showed, true after?/

Comment: thank you !! but my problem is setting a empty sharedprfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `setting.getString("dialogShow", "0")` means something like `getString(name, defaultValue)` then the default is `"0"` if the preference hasn't been set yet, which means the dialog will never be shown even once. Perhaps you mean `setting.getString("dialogShow", "1")`.